# How can I fetch/save image from dynamic url in PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

How can I fetch/save image from dynamic url like this?

http://www.groove3.com/str/image.php?type=P&id=16470

I am using function below but it doesn't work on dynamic urls:

```
function saveImage($image_url,$save_to){
    if(!file_exists($save_to) && $image_url != "")
    {
        $ch = curl_init($image_url);
        $fp = fopen($save_to, 'wb');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$image_url);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp); 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file_get_contents` instead.

```
$img_content = file_get_contents($image_url);
//Save the file in file system.
$fp = fopen($save_to, "w");
fwrite($fp, $img_content);
fclose($fp);
```